Mayer-Vietoris for finite cover of 1-complex
Let $X$ be a finite 1-complex, and let $\{U_i\}$ be a cover of $X$. Then consider the sequence of first homology groups
$$... \to \oplus_{i<j<k}H_1(U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k) \to \oplus_{i<j}H_1(U_i \cap U_j) \to \oplus_{i}H_1(U_i) \to H_1(X)$$
I know in general this is a chain complex and it is on the first page of the Mayer-Vietoris spectral sequence. However, can $X$ being a 1-complex tell us something more? Is this sequence exact?

Have you tried some examples? Say, some standard open covers of the circle?

@Thorgott Thanks, I see it is not exact. In general, can we say something about the sequence knowing $X$ is a 1-complex?
